# INSERT statement works only once

Tags: php, mysql, insertion

I asked something like this earlier, but now I ran better tests, and tried to analyze what the problem was.
This is the ajax request:

```
  //start ajax request here//
   $.post('purchaseitem.php',{itemAmount:itemAmount, itemId:itemId}, function(data){
    $('.savestatus_'+itemId).text(data);
   });
  //end it here
```

I echo out all the items in the items table, along with an ahref link and an input field to allow the user to type in the quantity and click buy.

```
<?php
    $shop_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sector0_item WHERE item_location = '$chapter'");
    while(($shop_row = mysql_fetch_array($shop_query))){
        $itemid = $shop_row['item_id'];
        $item_name = $shop_row['item_name'];
        $item_price = $shop_row['item_price'];
        ?>
        <div class = "item_name"><?php echo $item_name; ?></div> 
        <div class = "item_price"><?php echo $item_price; ?></div> 
        <input type = 'text' class = "purchaseAmount_<?php echo $itemid;?>" name = "purchaseAmount" />
        <a id = "purchaseButton_<?php echo $itemid; ?>" href = "prevent default();" class = "purchase_button" onclick = "buy(); return false;">Buy</a>
        <div class = 'savestatus_<?php echo $itemid; ?>'></div>
        <hr /><br />
        <?php
    }
?>
```

This is a test version of my code, so I know that it is messed up...
The php part:

```
$user_inventory_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sector0_inventory WHERE id = '$dbid' AND item_id = '$item_id'");
                        $checking_item_inventory = mysql_num_rows($user_inventory_query);
                        if($checking_item_inventory === 0){
                            /*^*/  $insertion_into_inventory = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `sector0_inventory`(`id`, `item_id`, `username`, `item_name`, `quantity`) VALUES ('$dbid','$item_id','$dbuser','$item_name','$purchase_amount')");
                                if($insertion_into_inventory === true){
                                mysql_query("UPDATE sector0_players SET cash = cash-'$total_cost' WHERE id = '$dbid'");
                                echo "Purchase complete";
                                }
                        }else if ($checking_item_inventory === 1){
                            $update_inventory_quantities = mysql_query("UPDATE sector0_inventory SET quantity = quantity+'$purchase_amount' WHERE id = '$dbid' AND item_id = '$item_id'");
                            if($update_inventory_quantities===true) {
                                mysql_query("UPDATE sector0_players SET cash = cash-'$total_cost' WHERE id = '$dbid'");
                                echo "Purchase complete, quantity updated.";
                                }
                        }
```

The above is the query. the /*^*/ part is the part that fails.
When I Truncate the table, and click buy, the insertion is completely successful. But for any other item, insertion fails. It's a php, I guess, I am really confused.
relative table to the insert and update queries

```
CREATE TABLE `sector0_inventory` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The input in this field will be php code exclusive. No increment allowed.',
 `item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The input is also code exclusive',
 `username` varchar(250) NOT NULL COMMENT 'This value will be used to search for the user inventory information. Admin privileges only',
 `item_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL COMMENT 'This value will be used to identify (user side) the item. It will be used by admins to query out when a removal of a specific item is needed',
 `quantity` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'This value will be 0 by default BIG int is to allow calculations',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: I hope you sanitized those variables...

Comment: I have a very hard-coded custom function to sanitize every sort of user-input variable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the output of `CREATE TABLE sector0_item` to get more help, but my guess is that your primary key on that table is `id` and you're trying to specify that manually in your INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO `sector0_inventory`(`id`, `item_id`, `username`, `item_name`, `quantity`) VALUES ('$dbid','$item_id','$dbuser','$item_name','$purchase_amount')
```

Your primary key must be unique for each row. Try:

```
INSERT INTO `sector0_inventory`(`item_id`, `username`, `item_name`, `quantity`) VALUES ('$item_id','$dbuser','$item_name','$purchase_amount')
```

That will work if your `id` column is set to `AUTO INCREMENT`.

EDIT: After you posted the table structure, your problem is the database table design. Right now the primary key is `id` which means you can only have one row per PHP session ID. I don't know your application, but that seems wrong.

If you can delete the table and start from scratch, then DROP the table and re-create it using:

```
CREATE TABLE `sector0_inventory` (
 `transaction_key` INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT COMMENT 'The unique ID for each row',
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The input in this field will be php code exclusive.     No increment allowed.',
 `item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The input is also code exclusive',
 `username` varchar(250) NOT NULL COMMENT 'This value will be used to search for the     user inventory information. Admin privileges only',
 `item_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL COMMENT 'This value will be used to identify (user     side) the item. It will be used by admins to query out when a removal of a         specific item is needed',
 `quantity` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'This value will be 0 by default BIG int is to     allow calculations',
 PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

then restore your PHP back to the way you had it.

Note that this will forfeit all of your data in that table...

Comment: The first id column is inserted/valued as the user's session/cookie ID
It is a bigint(20), item_id is the same, username is a varchar, item_name is varchar, quantity is bigint(20).
I will try to add an auto increment index field, and retry the the insertion.

Comment: Edit the question to include the output of `SHOW CREATE sector0_inventory` and that will help.

Comment: Updated to include another solution.

Comment: This really did work! Thanks for, not only the answer, but also the explanation, much appreciated!